# Site visitors with read permissions getting access denied?

Tags: 2013, permissions, sharepoint-on-prem, survey

Ran into a strange permission issue I can't seem to figure out.

Objective: set up an anonymous survey that, on submission, redirects to a "thank you" page.

Set up:

Survey list set up on https://server/sites/rootweb/subsite/lists/survey

Subsite has broken permission inheritance from Rootweb.  Subsite Visitors group set to include `NT AUTHORITY\authenticated users`, with Read permissions at the Subsite level.

Survey list has broken inheritance from Subsite, with Subsite Visitors group (`NT AUTHORITY\authenticated users`) given Contribute permissions to the survey.

Site Pages, and `SitePages/ThankYou.aspx`, inherit permissions from Subsite, so Visitors (`NT AUTHORITY\authenticated users`) should have Read permissions.

Given the following link:

```
https://server/sites/rootweb/subsite/lists/survey/NewForm.aspx?Source=https://server/sites/rootweb/subsite/SitePages/ThankYou.aspx
```

expected behavior is that users get to the New form for the survey, enter their response, and on submission, get redirected to the "thank you" page.

What actually happens is that users see the New form (no issues there), upon submission of the survey, they see `Sorry, you don't have access to this page`, and *their survey submission is not saved*, with no error about failure to save a new list item.

We also tried a test using the default New form URL, which has a Source param which should redirect back to the "Overview" view of the list, which supposedly Visitors have Contribute permissions to, but again, no survey response is saved and users see the `Sorry, you don't have access to this page` error.

What's surprising to me is that, considering users are getting that error for a Site Pages page they should have Read access for, and a view of a list they should have Contribute access to, they are NOT getting that error for the New form of the survey and can actually access that.

Can anyone shed some light on what is going on here and why it's not working as we are expecting?

This is SP 2013 on-prem, if that matters.

Comment: try giving the users as well read access to site assets library.

Comment: @MarekSarad they already do - Site Asset inherits permissions from the site, where the default Visitors group has read access.